# Instead of pick-list field how to create radio button in salesforce lightning component

Tags: radio-button, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have created a page with lightening components as shown the below image, I want to change my pick-List field into radio button next to picklist option to choose the appropriate selection, can someone please help to create radio buttons instead of pickList filed
in the component I have used below code

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <ui:inputSelect label="Race Type" 
                                        aura:id="Type" 
                                        class="slds-select" 
                                        labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                        value="{!v.newRace.Race_Type__c}" />
                    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could someone please confirm if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something in line with [this:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/example) (replace v.Name with attribute that contains the name of the race):

```
<aura:component>
<lightning:radioGroup name="radioGroup"
                      label="slds-form-element__label"
                      options="{! v.newRace.Race_Type__c }"
                      value="{! v.Name}"
                      type="radio"/>
</aura:component>
```